# Does C have a #include<bitset> similar to C++?

Tags: c, bitset

Does C have a `#include<bitset>` similar to C++ ? I have been looking for the past week. I can't find a equivalent directive preprocessor!

Comment: No, there is no *standard* header for this.

Comment: That would be hard to do considering C doesn't have templates.

Comment: Probably the closest thing in C is the built-in bitwise operators (eg bool isThirdBitSet = ((someVal & (1<<2)) != 0); )

Comment: There are some third-party header-only libraries you can find on GitHub, I am not aware of any standard headers.

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/263738/5754656 (and other answers to that question) might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. There are, however, ways to implement what you are looking for (or at least some sort of approximation). Take look at: http://c-faq.com/misc/bitsets.html - I think it is going to be useful.